# Zooming qgraphicsview with mouse wheel and ctrl

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt, pyqt5, scale

I'm trying to implement zoom using a combination of Ctrl key and mouse wheel. But I came across the fact that when the cursor is inside QGraphicsView, the position of the scrollbar changes along with scaling. How to fix it?
Here is the code I am using:

```
    class MyWin(QMainWindow, QGraphicsView):

        def __init__(self):  # constructor
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ...
        def wheelEvent(self, event):
            modifiers = QtWidgets.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
            if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
               if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                   self.on_zoom_in()
               elif event.angleDelta().y() < 0:
                   self.on_zoom_out()
```

Comment: The behavior depends on how you want to zoom, and those zoom functions *must* consider the position of the mouse mapped to the scene in order to work properly. Note that you should not call the QApplication `keyboardModifiers()`, as QWheelEvent (which inherits from QInputEvent) already provides the [`modifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputevent.html#modifiers) used for that event.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you very much for unswer! I'll use modifiers()! But I didn't quite understand the rest. Do I need to define an event so that the cursor is in the QGraphicsView area?

Comment: If you get a wheel event, it must be happening in the QGraphicsView area (otherwise it will not be received). You must map the position of the mouse to the scene. Please read about the [Graphics View coordinate system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) and all the QGraphicsView `mapTo*()` and `mapFrom*()` functions.